# How can i set firefox to be my default Remote JS Debugger for React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I don't have chrome installed for some reason. When I hit "debug JS remotely", i get a log saying, "chrome wasn't found", and when i try to access the url in firefox : http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui, it doesn't work.

I want to debug in Firefox browser. How can i change the default settings for react-native remote JS debugger.

Answer (score 8):

Step1: Put the URL in your Firefox/Opera browser: http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui

Step2: Open the Console ( Ctrl+Shift+J or Cmd+Shift+J )

Step3: Hit Cmd+D on Simulator and select "Debug JS Remotely"

Step4: Hit Cmd+R on Simulator

Step5: Check the Console in the Browser

These steps will work for Opera Browser also

This works for me.

Comment: How do I set which browser I want it to open with when I start the app? My opens in FF and I want it to be Chrome w/o having to do all these manual steps.

Comment: @MoteZart I think this is because your default browser is FF. When you click "Debug JS Remotely" it opens the debug URL in your default browser. 

One way to solve this is to set "Chrome" as your default browser.

Answer (score -2):

To use a custom JavaScript debugger in place of Chrome Developer Tools, set the REACT_DEBUGGER environment variable to a command that will start your custom debugger. You can then select "Debug JS Remotely" from the Developer Menu to start debugging.

The debugger will receive a list of all project roots, separated by a space. For example, if you set REACT_DEBUGGER="node /path/to/launchDebugger.js --port 2345 --type ReactNative", then the command node /path/to/launchDebugger.js --port 2345 --type ReactNative /path/to/reactNative/app will be used to start your debugger

for more info check this:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging

Comment: I read that already, but how do I set REACT_DEBUGGER environment variable? If by environment variable you mean, System environment variables in windows, where we define path, I did that already, doesn't work!

Comment: Open the debugger
1.select "Debugger" from the Web Developer submenu in the Firefox Menu (or Tools menu if you display the menu bar or are on Mac OS X)
2.press the Ctrl Shift S ( Command Option S on OS X) keyboard shortcut.
3.press the menu button ( ), press "Developer", then select "Debugger".